# Add default value to button in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a button and I want to put normal is the default value of this button. I have change ng-swich-default to normal but it not catch data from normal in the drop down. It shows only letter. How can I do it with AngularJS? I have never used it as before. Below code:

```
 <span class="priority-select btn-group" dropdown>
    <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
        dropdown-toggle>
        <img
            ng-if="form.priority === undefined"
            src="images/task_approval/priority/priority-create.png"
            alt="priority"/>
        <img
            ng-if="form.priority !== undefined"
            ng-src="images/task_approval/priority/{{form.priority}}.png"
            alt="priority"/>
        <span ng-switch="form.priority">
            <span
                ng-switch-when="high"
                class="btn-text"
                translate>High
            </span>
            <span
                ng-switch-when="normal"
                class="btn-text"
                translate>Normal
            </span>
            <span
                ng-switch-when="low"
                class="btn-text"
                translate>Low
            </span>
            <span
                ng-switch-default
                class="btn-text"
                translate>Priority
            </span>
        </span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li>
            <a ng-click="set_priority('high')">
                <img src="images/task_approval/priority/high.png" alt="high"/>
                <span translate>High</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a ng-click="set_priority('normal')">
                <img src="images/task_approval/priority/normal.png" alt="normal"/>
                <span translate>Normal</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a ng-click="set_priority('low')">
                <img src="images/task_approval/priority/low.png" alt="low"/>
                <span translate>Low</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must declare set_priority() function and change form.priority value with your parameter.

or

you can change inside ng-click in "a" tag.
Something like this:
ng-click="formPriority='high'"

and then

ng-switch="formPriority"

```
<span class="priority-select btn-group" dropdown>
    <button ng-init='formPriority="normal"'
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
        dropdown-toggle>
        <img
            ng-if="formPriority == undefined"
            src="images/task_approval/priority/priority-create.png"
            alt="priority"/>
        <img
            ng-if="formPriority != undefined"
            ng-src="images/task_approval/priority/{{formPriority}}.png"
            alt="priority"/>
        <span ng-switch="formPriority">
            <span
                ng-switch-when="high"
                class="btn-text"
                translate>High
            </span>
            <span
                ng-switch-when="normal"
                class="btn-text"
                translate>Normal
            </span>
            <span
                ng-switch-when="low"
                class="btn-text"
                translate>Low
            </span>
            <span
                ng-switch-default
                class="btn-text"
                translate>Priority
            </span>
        </span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li>
            <a ng-click='formPriority="high"'>
                <img src="images/task_approval/priority/high.png" alt="high"/>
                <span translate>High</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a ng-click='formPriority="normal"'>
                <img src="images/task_approval/priority/normal.png" alt="normal"/>
                <span translate>Normal</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a ng-click='formPriority="low"'>
                <img src="images/task_approval/priority/low.png" alt="low"/>
                <span translate>Low</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</span>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to change it. Could you show the sample?

Comment: sorry, It doesn't work. It not catch data from normal on drop down with the image as a default for this button. @a.u.b